# MySQL syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement with hash column names

Tags: php, mysql

I am parsing xls/csv files into database. For each file I have one table with columns named by hashes of file column names.

For columns

- Nazwisko
- Imię
- Adres1
- Adres2
- Miasto
- Telefon
- Kod
- Email
- Województwo

I have SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE premium_import_temp_worksheet_9 (
id                       INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
f37c4446e4a882972cd3a80053dd795f VARCHAR(255),
d5bfdd6746ff1a364399acb6e6526b7a VARCHAR(255),
f7e2db7542ea17f0fcc1a46ee21f860b VARCHAR(255),
7161b0ab070daf8e20a2b62f2ef13b81 VARCHAR(255),
4f4e297d754b67e7a104f58b2bcdb850 VARCHAR(255),
0975cf6baccb3862c31522c2b5b8fabc VARCHAR(255),
d1c0419824dea874935502cf6d7c946f VARCHAR(255),
ce8ae9da5b7cd6c3df2929543a9af92d VARCHAR(255),
d7f1213d49993b7ce9ce02463ea1eeda VARCHAR(255),
                 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

and everything is executed without any errors, but for:

- Company Name
- Phone
- sffd
- sdf
- sdfff

I have:

```
CREATE TABLE premium_import_temp_worksheet_8 (
id                       INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
e7b47c58815acf1d3afa59a84b5db7fb VARCHAR(255),
bcc254b55c4a1babdf1dcb82c207506b VARCHAR(255),
6e87a4f6ea8244d7e04cb52e495d6693 VARCHAR(255),
d9729feb74992cc3482b350163a1a010 VARCHAR(255),
c90e651df62a9057d9bc8f48b42da7d0 VARCHAR(255),
                 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

And error:

> mysqlt error: [1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '6e87a4f6ea8244d7e04cb52e495d6693 VARCHAR(255),
>   d9729feb74992cc3482b350163a1a010 ' at line 5] in EXECUTE("CREATE TABLE
>   premium_import_temp_worksheet_7 ( id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   e7b47c58815acf1d3afa59a84b5db7fb VARCHAR(255),
>   bcc254b55c4a1babdf1dcb82c207506b VARCHAR(255),
>   6e87a4f6ea8244d7e04cb52e495d6693 VARCHAR(255),
>   d9729feb74992cc3482b350163a1a010 VARCHAR(255),
>   c90e651df62a9057d9bc8f48b42da7d0 VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (id) )
>   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci")

I don't know what is the difference between syntaxes of these two statements. Please help.

Comment: try adding backticks ` ` for each col name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are observing appears to be a bug.   As excerpted from the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html):

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

The confusion appears to be due to the fact that "6e87" is a valid number, even though it does not consist entirely of digits.  This is exponential notation.  For some reason, although an unquoted identifier *can* start with a digit, it cannot start with a number in exponential notation.

This is easy enough to fix by quoting the identifiers with either backticks or double quotes.

EDIT:

You can replicate the problem with these two simple queries:

```
select 6 as 5_1

select 6 as 5e1

select 6 as 5f1

select 6 as 5e1f
```

The first and third work.  The second correctly fails because the identifier is a number (in exponential form).  The last fails incorrectly.
By the way, I think it is a bad idea to start identifiers with numbers, but that is a separate matter from MySQL behaving the way it is documented to behave.

Comment: really strange :) , first table starts by numbers and its created without error , second thrown error :) .

Answer (score 2):

you should escape  by backticks

try this

```
   CREATE TABLE premium_import_temp_worksheet_8 (
 id                       INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 e7b47c58815acf1d3afa59a84b5db7fb VARCHAR(255),
 bcc254b55c4a1babdf1dcb82c207506b VARCHAR(255),
 `6e87a4f6ea8244d7e04cb52e495d6693` VARCHAR(255),
 d9729feb74992cc3482b350163a1a010 VARCHAR(255),
 c90e651df62a9057d9bc8f48b42da7d0 VARCHAR(255),
             PRIMARY KEY (id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03d6fd

Comment: The can start with numbers, but the docs do not appear to be correct: _Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits._  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html It does _not_ say that they must be quoted if they begin with a number, though that is what has happened here.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03d6fd

Comment: yes i know the docs said it , but its bug i think , they work anyway. but better escape by backtickes :)

Comment: MySQL explicitly documents and supports unquoted identifiers starting with numbers.  See my answer.